# Split a Range of Dates into hourly records

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have the following type of date in my data:

```
21.02.2015 08:00 - 21.02.2015 14:59 (CET) content1 content2
```

I now want to split the time into hourly time rows which contain the same contents as the row above (above I want it to be splitted until 14:00). How could I do this for the whole dataframe?

I would have started with converting like this:

```
def split_timerange(date1, date2):
    start= datetime.datetime.strptime(date1,'%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:S')
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:S')
    timerangehourly = pd.date_range(start,end,freq='H')
```

I do not know how to create for each element of the dataframe 'timerangehourly' a seperate column with the contents of the range. Any ideas? Thanks!

Additional info how the data looks like:

```
21.02.2015 08:00 - 21.02.2015 14:59 (CET)   Cancelled outage    Planned 
outage  Generation Unit     CTA|DE(50Hertz) PSW Markersbach PSS B   174 0
```

These are all the columns I have. 
What whould be perfect would be a transformation that in the first columns there is the time and it says which power station (e.g.'PSW Markersbach') has an outage. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Can you add more data with desired output? Dates ranges are overlapping? Dates are in one day only?

Comment: Do you already have the dataframe or you have a text which needs to be splitted?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful. Thank you.